# How can I hide the inherited menu strip?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've got a form that needs to inherit a base form. The problem is that the base form has a menu strip. The form I'm working on should not have any kind of menu on it.

How can I hide the inherited menu strip? Alternatively, how can I exchange the inherited menu for something I construct myself in the new form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the base form class, extract the menu strip creation code from InitializeComponent() into a virtual method, and then override that method in the new form. The drawback of this is you lose visual designer support for the menu in the base form.

Comment: Does this mean I have to find every other form that inherits the base form and make sure the new initialization method is called? Because that's not an option I'm afraid.

Comment: No: if you call the menu initialization method from Load in the base form, all you need to do is to override the method in those instances when you don't want the menu to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way, which I actually ended up using.

If you don't need to show the menu again in that particular form, you can initialize all the components as usual. Then simply make a public method like `HideMainMenu()` in your base class, that you call after all Init's are run, which only does this:

> ```
> Public Sub HideMainMenu()
>     Me.Menu = Nothing
> End Sub
> ```

You could probably show the menu again by doing

> ```
> Public Sub ShowMainMenu()
>     Me.Menu = Me.myPrivateMainMenu
> End Sub
> ```

But I haven't tried that...